# Prove that f is not Differentiable

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

i have the following question:
Let $f$ be defined in the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, and for all $a$ in $(0,1)$:$$f(a,0)=f(0,a)=f(a,a)=a$$
Prove that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. I've tried to suppose that $f$ is differentiable, so it follows that it's continuous at $(0,0)$, and then prove by definition that it can't be, but i get lost there. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely you mean $f$ is defined on the *disk* $x^2 + y^2 < 1$?

Comment: Your approach won't work since there are continuous functions that match the conditions. For example an inverted cone. Instead show that the partial derivatives at the origin cannot be continuous

Comment: @OpenBall it's ironic that you are the one to comment on this, given your name. I figured that must be what he's talking about, since the origin was mentioned. Also calculus 3 students don't often distinguish between the two, which can be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's differentiable at $0$, then it's continuous at $0$, so $\lim_{(a,b) \to (0,0)} f(a,b) = f(0,0)$. Since the limit exists, it should be the same along all paths, in particular along the path $b = 0$, hence $f(0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0} f(a,0) = \lim_{a\to 0} a = 0$. Now:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{f(a+0,0) -f(0,0)}{a} = \lim_{a \to 0} 1 = 1$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{f(0,0+a) -f(0,0)}{a} = \lim_{a \to 0} 1 = 1$$

Recall that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ iff:

$$\lim_{(a,b) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(0+a,0+b) -f(0,0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) a - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = 0$$

In particular, the above limit should be $0$ along the path $b=a$. However,

$$\frac{f(0+a,0+b) -f(0,0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) a - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = \frac{f(a,b) - a - b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} =_{\text{ if }b = a} \frac{-a}{\sqrt 2 |a|} \not \to 0$$